# Ошибка в txt файле из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, list, txt

при переводе элементов списка на русском языке в txt файл появляются эти символы:

�������

обратно в список эти:

пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ

как это решить?

```
import os.path
bc = []
if 'voice_assist_bc.txt' in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    path = Path('voice_assist_bc.txt')
    sbc = path.read_text()
    bc = sbc.split(',')

else:
    my_file = open("voice_assist_bc.txt", "w")
    my_file.close()
```

↑ это из txt в список

↓ это из списка в txt

```
with open("voice_assist_bc.txt", "w") as file:
    print(*bc, file=file)
```

p.s. эта конструкция нужна для сохранения нужных данных после закрытия скрипта и при открытии их возобновлении

Comment: указывайте явно кодировки - посмотрите синтаксис ваших операций с файлами

Comment: а как это сделать?
`#-*- coding utf-8 -*-`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто укажите кодировку.

```py
... open("voice_assist_bc.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') ...
```